# C# - ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, wpf, database, oledb, ms-access-2013

I'm using OleDbConnection to connect to a MS Access 2013 database with C# Visual studio 2013 with WPF and I'm using the facade design pattern in my connection class -

```
public class Connection
{
    private readonly OleDbConnection con;
    private readonly string path;
    private bool connected;

    public Connection(string path)
    {
        connected = false;
        this.path = path;
        string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + ";";
        this.con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
    }

    public string Path { get { return path; } }
    public bool Connected { get { return connected; } }

    public void Open()
    {
        this.con.Open();
        connected = true;
    }

    public DataSet GetData(string sql) // get dataset of with data of this sql query
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }

    public T GetItem<T>(string sql) // get an single item
    {
        return (T) GetData(sql).Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
    }

    public void Execute(string sql) // execute Insert, Delete etc..
    {
        OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand();
        ocmd.CommandText = sql;
        ocmd.Connection = con;
        Execute(ocmd);  

    }

    public void Execute(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.con.Close();
        connected = false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[Connection: Path=" + path + "Connected=" + connected + " ]";
    }

}
```

the `GetData` method works. The `Execute` method seems like it works but when I look at the database it doesn't change anything, the wierd thing is this :

```
Connection db = new Connection("Database\\Database.accdb");
db.Open();
int count = db.GetItem<int>("SELECT COUNT(ScoreID) FROM tblScores");
Console.WriteLine(count); // prints 1
db.Execute("INSERT INTO tblScores VALUES (1, 'My Awsome Name', 'Easy', 3, Date())");
count = db.GetItem<int>("SELECT COUNT(ScoreID) FROM tblScores");
Console.WriteLine(count); // prints 2 (??)
db.Close();
```

After running this I look in the database and I don't see the row..
I tried to run the query directly on access (opening MS Access 2013) and it worked, Also when I try to execute the query with a primary key that is already inside it throws an exception, so what is the problem here?

Comment: try:

int result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


and check to ensure result equals 1 and not 0

Comment: I tried, the result is 1

Comment: Then you are probably looking at the wrong database.

Comment: I'm running this code couple times and each time it prints 1 and 2

Comment: I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that you're inserting an Id column... if you wrap your `INSERT` in a try catch do you receive any issues?

Comment: I solved it, It was creating a new database file each time i run the program an I wasn't looking at the right one..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Execute(string sql) // execute Insert, Delete etc..
{
    OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand();
    ocmd.CommandText = sql;
    ocmd.Connection = con;
    Execute(ocmd);  

}

public void Execute(OleDbCommand cmd)
{
    try
    {
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

also the problem might be in your INSERT statement - in Access database, Date must be wrapped up in # signs:

```
"INSERT INTO tblScores VALUES (1, 'My Awsome Name', 'Easy', 3, #" + DateTime.Now() + "#)"
```

Comment: this is not the problem, the query works great when I execute it in MS Access 2013, and it needs to throw an exception if it is a Syntax Error, I used the Date() function of MS Access

Comment: I tried adding # and also use the Date() function of access, and it was syntax error probably because the Date() function returns the date in the correct format

Comment: use either Datetime.Today to get just the date or DateTime.Now to get data and time